# How to show form data in same div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying show form data within same div after click on submit button but without form.In current code,after click on submit button hidden div is not appearing. Please go through below code which I have tried and refer to image attached of desire output. In which title and description should come in same div in replace of form.

Someone help me out where I am going wrong with code.Thanks. 
[https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lorem_Ipsum_Helvetica.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl2xc.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script>
     function fn(){
      var fn = document.getElementById("f1").value;
      var des = document.getElementById("t1").value;
      
      var mainDiv = document.getElementById("d2");
      var div = document.getElementById("d1");
      if(mainDiv.style.display==="block"){
       
       mainDiv.style.display="none";
       div.style.display="block";
      }
      document.getElementById("fn1").innerHTML = fn;
      document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = des;
     }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div style ="height:400px; width:500px; border:1px solid black; display:block;" id="d2">
    <form>
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fn" id="f1" /><br /><br />
    Description: <textarea id="t1" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="b1" id="b1" value="Add" onclick="add()"  />
    <input type="submit" name="b1" id="b2" value="Cancel" onclick="Cancel()"  />
    </form>
    </div>

    <div style ="height:400px; width:500px; border:1px solid black; display:none;" id="d1">
     <p><span id="fn1"></span></p>
     <p><span id="t2"></span></p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, few things were wrong.

1. The `if` part of the function isn't needed in this case if you're not validating the imput in the field (if you need so, you can comment and I'll add it for you)
2. The buttons to ***Add*** and ***Cancel*** were `submit` type, so, as soon as you click it, even if you had the write code on JS, they'd vanish right after showing, because they'd be submited as a form.
3. You were calling ***`add()`*** and ***`Cancel()`*** on the `onClick` events, which haven't been declared in any JS functions.

Well, after all, I just changed the type of the inputs from `submit` to `button`, added a CSS part for better view of the elements that you're working with and changed the JavaScript part just to do what you were asking to. See if it helps :

```css
.d2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}

.d1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script>
     function myFunction(){
      var fn = document.getElementById("f1").value;
      var des = document.getElementById("t1").value;
      var fDiv = document.getElementById("d2"); //fDiv stands for "Form Div"
      var hDiv = document.getElementById("d1"); // hDiv stands for "Hidden Div"
        
        hDiv.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("fn1").innerHTML = fn;
      document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = des;
        fDiv.style.display = "none";
        
     }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div name="form" id="d2" class="d2">
      <form>
      First Name: <input type="text" name="fn" id="f1" /><br /><br />
      Description: <textarea id="t1" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea><br /><br />
      <input type="button" name="b1" id="b1" value="Add" onclick="myFunction()"  />
      <input type="button" name="b1" id="b2" value="Cancel" onclick="Cancel()"  />
      </form>
    </div>

    <div name="hidden" id="d1" class="d1">
     <p><span id="fn1"></span></p>
     <p><span id="t2"></span></p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Any questions, you can comment and ask.

Comment: One thing I want ask. When I have given input type submit for button and refresh the page after getting the values, the form was coming with null values(like simply a form design). But I wrote input type button and refresh the page, the form shows existing values. Why is that?@Matheus Simoes

Comment: @micky As the code is wrote, the form saves the last inputs in the fields to manage and prevent losing data, if you want to always want to clear the form whenever the page is loaded, just add an `onLoad()` parameter on the `<body>` and create another function in JS to simple clear the form, a tip : `innerHTML = "";`

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks for the help!